# Different Controller conflicts - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have two controller with different names and same structure. After injecting both on same page while performing action on one then it is reflecting on other one also.

Comment: Have you read about child and parent controllers?

Comment: try controllerAs syntax: `<div ng-controller="Ctrl1 as c1"> {{c1.data}} ...`

Comment: you are likely to have problems with your code - provide something